# QueryString not reading in Servlet - NullPointer Exception

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, query-string

I have a simple case of calling a servlet with query parameters on a button click. The issue is, in the servlet when I try to read the query parameters, I am getting null.

This is my jsp code snippet.

```
<form action="http://localhost:8080/ChartsApp/apps/CreateXMLServlet?r=0.7180008697323501&fc=03&fc=04&fc=05">
    <input type="submit" title="Submit"/>
</form>
```

This is my servlet code snippet in the doPost

```
System.out.println(request.getQueryString());
String[] selectedCodes = (String[]) request.getParameterValues("fc");
if (selectedCodes != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < selectedCodes.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("fc[" + i + "] = " + selectedCodes[i]);
    }
}
```

The first sout is printing null, and I am getting nullpointer exception in the subsequent lines. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think u miss to set form method post ..

Comment: If you submit the form the servlet should execute doPost

Comment: @Neha you are right. Addign the method worked. If you answer I shall accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the "post" method in form tag to access the request parameters.

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/ChartsApp/apps/CreateXMLServlet?r=0.7180008697323501&fc=03&fc=04&fc=05">
<input type="submit" title="Submit"/>
```